# Extjs 4 carousel

Tags: javascript, slideshow, extjs4.1, carousel

I need a carousel/slideshow that can be inserted in a Panel for extjs 4.1. I found the Ext core carousel, but it doesn't seem to work correctly.

Is there a such thing? If not, how can I modify the Ext core carousel to adapt it for my needs?

Thanks

Comment: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?145146-ExtJS-4-and-Ext-Core-Carousel

Comment: I tried, it doesn't work... Is there something directly made with Ext 4? I mean it's a pretty common feature!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know if this post is useful for you : http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?256456-an-Ext-JS-4-carousel-component&p=938789#post938789

http://code.google.com/p/ext-js-carousel/wiki/Introduction

Comment: It isn't really the what I need, but it might be useful thanks. I successfully modified the Ext.core version to make it work.